# Apache HIVE JDBC: How to customize SSL certificate validation?

Tags: java, ssl, jdbc, hive

I wonder how I can customize the SSL certificate validation for the Apache HIVE JDBC driver in Java. This includes enabling the use of self-signed certificates as well as ignoring other validation errors.

This is the code throwing an error:

```
// using library hive-jdbc-3.1.2-standalone.jar
Class.forName("org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver"); 
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive2://somethingsomethinghere.azurehdinsight.net:443/default;transportMode=http;ssl=true;httpPath=/hive2", "user@somedomain.com", "ultra-secure password");
```

If the code would work, a connection to HIVE would be established and `con` would be set accordingly. Instead I get this error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Could not open client transport with JDBC Uri: jdbc:hive2://somethingsomethinghere.azurehdinsight.net:443/default;transportMode=http;ssl=true;httpPath=/hive2: Could not establish connection to jdbc:hive2://somethingsomethinghere.azurehdinsight.net:443/default;transportMode=http;ssl=true;httpPath=/hive2;sasl.qop=auth: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Host name '123.123.123.123' does not match the certificate subject provided by the peer (CN=*.azurehdinsight.net)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.<init>(HiveConnection.java:256)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver.connect(HiveDriver.java:107)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at MyFancyButNotWorkingClass.main(MyFancyButNotWorkingClass.java:102)
```

It is rather obvious that added the certificate to the key store does not help as it seems to be for the wrong server. However, my (vain) hope was that a trusted certificate would be accepted even if used by a different server (which clearly would break the concept of SSL server certificates for authentication).

Some certificates can be made trustworthy by adding them to a local key store, e.g. the sample certificate of https://self-signed.badssl.com. This is how it is added to a key store:

```
%JAVA_HOME%\bin\keytool.exe" -import -file <CERTIFICATE-FILE-NAME> -alias <SOME-NAME> -keystore my-sample-store
```

The general approach to configure the SSL validation process is documented in [Apache HTTP Components - Connection Management - SSL](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/connmgmt.html#d5e449). With this documentation (and some research on in this forum and others) I ended up with this code:

```
    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getDefault();
    HostnameVerifier hostnameVerifier = new NoopHostnameVerifier();
    SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext, hostnameVerifier);
    Registry<ConnectionSocketFactory> socketFactoryRegistry = RegistryBuilder.<ConnectionSocketFactory> create().register("http", PlainConnectionSocketFactory.getSocketFactory()).register("https", sslSocketFactory).build();
```

As this had no effect I looked into the implementation of [HiveConnection.java](https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/a69e676e90dd023072fb15d384f41ddb7a164445/jdbc/src/java/org/apache/hive/jdbc/HiveConnection.java#L602) and found that the `SSLConnectionSocketFactory` is initialized using a non-configurable `DefaultHostnameVerifier`.

Am I missing something here? Is there a way to set JVM-wide standard HTTP Client Factory settings that the HIVE implementation will then use?

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. Can you please add some more detail about the expected behavior and what you observed?

Answer (score 0):

If It's any consolation, Hive JDBC `version < 3.x` jars are working even with `DefaultHostnameVerifier`.
There is a Github issue opened for the same error [Link](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/15146)